# Create a flow to move all documents from recycle bin to another library

Tags: automation, sharepoint-2010, power-automate

I'm trying to build a power automate flow to move the documents from the recycle bin to another library.

In more detail, I want schedule flow to loop to a series of SharePoint sites and copy all documents from the recycle bin to another library.

1. An array that will contain all sites

[image: Array with sites]

2. For each site, using an HTTP request to get all documents from the recycle bin. Filtering the URI to get only documents.

[image]

3. Move each document to another library.

In these step is where I'm stuck. How can I select the documents ? All outputs of my JSON action are “type”

[image]